# SSL Termination with HAProxy and Nginx on Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, ssl, haproxy, ubuntu-12.04, openssl

I've been following this tutorial:

http://www.exratione.com/2012/12/websockets-over-ssl-haproxy-nodejs-nginx/

...but I've been having problems connecting to Nginx through HAProxy via SSL.

I'm getting `Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.` in Chrome after the HTTP to HTTPS redirect and `(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)` in Firefox.

I think it has something to do with the concatenation of files to create a `.pem` file.

Things I've tried:

- Disabling HAProxy and accessing Nginx directly using SSL which works
- Not using SSL on HAProxy to access Nginx, this also works
- Creating new SSL certificates following these steps: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule
- Checking permissions on SSL certificate files

My Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen   8080 ssl; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
}
```

I also have 3 SSL files:

- `/etc/ssl/certs/server.crt`
- `/etc/ssl/private/server.key`
- both of which have been concatenated into `/etc/ssl/server.pem` key first cert second as the tutorial states.

To possibly further complicate things I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on `Vagrant`.

Thanks,

Ash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK there were a couple of problems with this.

The first is that I was enabling SSL in both HAProxy and Nginx which is unnecessary and would cause problems by itself. So I disabled SSL in my Nginx config and restarted.

The second problem was that I was attempting to access this server (which was on a Guest Virtual Machine) through `localhost` which worked partially because port 80 was being forwarded correctly. However when it came to redirecting `HTTP` traffic to `HTTPS` it would fail.

I'm guessing this is because HAProxy was redirect to another port.

Anyway accessing the server through the actual IP address works.

Comment: Your solution saves my days, thanks so much. I love you XXX